# Codename one native interface: package android.widget does not exist

Tags: android, native, codenameone

I have followed Shai's youtube tutorial on how to implement native interfaces into my codename one app. I create the interface in the `src` directory then generate the native access classes in the `Native` folder. However when I try to enter `android.widget.Button b = ...` I get an error message that says `package android.widget does not exist`. What am I doing wrong? The `NativeDemo` uses the exact same code.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android studio? Are you sure you have created Android Project ?

Comment: @zest I'm using netbeans. What do you mean by created an android project? I've created the codename one project in netbeans.

Comment: This package is placed inside Android SDK, check your path to framework in Netbeans. Here is the link where you can download latest version https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

Comment: @zest So once I download the sdk how do I link it to my cn1 project?

Comment: Probably I not understand Codename but here is the manual how to setup Android SDK https://forums.netbeans.org/topic51543.html in Netbeans

Comment: Seems like Codename has cloud build machine with all required dependencies have set already. But if you don't want to see the errors in your IDE and have code completion option you need to set paths for SDKs. For iOS seems like you'll need OS-X and you surely can't install WinPhone framework anywhere except Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a code completion issue, the build will work correctly see:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/c7PeUr8o-RQ/zVzk6FjsEgAJ